# Formula to Round

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

Currently in sharepoint what I have is a formula, that when Today Date-Create Date, gives me a difference of 205.55555 days. How can I change this formula to round the number to 206?

```
=IF([Current Status]="Argument 1","1", IF([Current Status]="Argument 2","2", IF([Current Status]="Argument 3","3",[Today’s Date]-[Create Date])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ROUNDUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/roundup-function-a92985d9-f99a-4ed4-9fd4-ad6e1d6f10b7) function and change your formula to this:

```
=IF([Current Status]="Argument 1","1", IF([Current Status]="Argument 2","2", IF([Current Status]="Argument 3","3",ROUNDUP([Today’s Date]-[Create Date],0))))
```

Also, you can use the today() function in the formula, instead of `[Today’s Date]`.